# C# Quotes in quotes (Regex Matching)

Tags: c#, html, css, regex, string-matching

I'm trying to use Regex.Match to match something, but it already has quotes in it, and it cancels the Regex.Match's quotes.
I have checked other threads but their answers didn't work for me.

```
Match divisionWinsLosses = Regex.Match(website, @"<span style="font-size: 18px; color: #6C0; height: 28px; text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;">(.*?)</span>");
```

Just in case. The HTML code from the website is this:`<span style="font-size: 18px; color: #6C0; height: 28px; text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;">[What I want is here]</span>`

Comment: If you really checked other threads, you'd know that [parsing html with regex is a really bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Use an html parser. HtmlAgilityPack is great.

Comment: I actually really did check other threads and decided that using something other than HtmlAgilityPack is easier for me. I have tried though..
Just personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes. In string literals, use `\"` (e.g. `"My name is \"Bob\"."`). In verbatim string literals, use `""` (e.g. `@"My name is ""Bob""."`). See [Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx).

```
Match divisionWinsLosses = Regex.Match(website, @"<span style=""font-size: 18px; color: #6C0; height: 28px; text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;"">(.*?)</span>");
```